# How to handle text edition from the KeyDown event?

Tags: c#, keydown

I would like to edit a graphical text (not a TextBox control) through the KeyDown event.
I need to update my text string according to the KeyEventArgs (key value and modifier).
I using a french keyboard for now but in the future I would like to support different keyboard layout.
How can I guess the caractere typed depending the key value, the modifier and the culture info?

I don't want to use the KeyPress event for technical reason.

Comment: `KeyPress` is probably the best general approach for text input, and culture-awareness is important. Great question. :)

Comment: @Me: Wait, why *don't* you want to use `KeyPress`? That event properly accounts for the repeat delay/rate for the system?

Comment: I used keypress in the end and solved my technical problem.

Comment: Consider closing this question or post your answer.

Comment: How can I close the question?

Comment: add the answer, then accept it. :-) You might even get a badge for doing that... (I think the answer needs to be voted up a certain amount too...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KeyPress is the best way to handle text input.